# How to read value from table, assign to variable and use it in x expr=\thisrow{}

Tags: pgfplots, external-files

How can I read the first value from the first column of a table, assign it to a variable and the use it in some math expression with x expr=\thisrow{}?

The code would be something like this, but in my example I'm manually typing the first value of the first column (3 in this example, as in `x expr=\thisrow{time}-3`) and I would like it to be done automatically.

UPDATE: My real table has between 5 and 6 columns and some thousands of rows. Please, this should be taken into account for the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
time speed
3 5
4 3
5 6
6 4
7 0
8 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=speed]
\addplot table[x expr=\thisrow{time}-3, y={speed}] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could read the element before you start the `axis` environment and save it to a macro using `\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{time}\of{data.dat}  
\edef\firstrowvalue{\pgfplotsretval}`. Then you can access it in your plot using `x expr=\thisrow{time}-\firstrowvalue`. Is that what you're looking for, or do you want an even more automatic solution (something like a `\firstrow{<column name>}` thata can be used directly in `x expr`, for example)?

Comment: I believe this solution would work for me. But I always get an error when I use `pgfplotstable` complaining about the size of the table. My real table is much bigger than that (thousands of rows) and 5--6 columns. From `pgfplots` manual section 4.2.3 > "1. If tables contain few rows and many columns, the ⟨\macro⟩ framework will be more efficient. 2. If tables contain more than 200 data points (rows), you should always use file input (and reload if
necessary)." I believe number 2 is my case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `\addplot file` instead of `\addplot table`, you can't use `x expr` or `\thisrow` or column names, because `file` expects a very simple two column layout. In this case, you could work with an `x filter` that checks whether its currently processing the first coordinate, and if it is, it saves the value to a global macro, which is then subtracted from all other coordinates:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
#time speed
3 5
4 3
5 6
6 4
7 0
8 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=time,ylabel=speed,
    x filter/.code={
        \ifnum\coordindex=0
            \xdef\firstvalue{\pgfmathresult}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-\firstvalue}
    }]
\addplot file {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this seem to solve for the example I've given. But my real table has between 5 and 6 columns, so I can't use addplot file.

Comment: @perr0: Can you plot your file successfully using `\addplot table`?

Comment: Yes, I can plot all five columns using `\addplot table`.

Comment: @perr0: But you can't use `\pgfplotstablegetelem`?

Comment: when I try to use `\pgfplotstablegetelem` with my real table I receive this error: "pgfplots: Table 'log_VS_vel.csv' appears to have too many colum". Just to be sure, I tried with this small table from the example and it works. So I really think the problem is the size of the real table.

Comment: @perr0: No, it looks like `\pgfplotstablegetelem` is stumbling over the column separator of the table. Could you post the first two lines of your table?

Comment: you were right, there was a mistake in the table header. It's working now, thank you very much.