# Stack lines by absolulte Y-offsets in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I need to shift several curves in a plot but in a way that is independent of the scale of the data. For example I need to shift each curve by a fifth or so of the scale of plot.

Suppose one has to plot several curves that are very similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
] coordinates{
 ( 1, 2 )
 ( 2, 3 )
 ( 3, 4 )
};
\addplot+[
] coordinates{
 ( 1, 2.1 )
 ( 2, 2.9 )
 ( 3, 4.1 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A common technique (if the background level is obvious) is to use a Y-offset. Like here: [image: originexample]

The obvious way would be to add a `filter` to shift the data (like below). However all the filters modify the data in a data coordinates not in units relative the axis size on paper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+0.0}\pgfmathresult}
    ] coordinates{
 ( 1, 2 )
 ( 2, 3 )
 ( 3, 4 )
};
\addplot+[
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+0.5}\pgfmathresult}
    ] coordinates{
 ( 1, 2.1 )
 ( 2, 2.9 )
 ( 3, 4.1 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**How can I shift the data (e.g. in the Y-direction) in proportion to the size of the axis?**

> I found this answer here after posting:
>   [How to do a shift/offset of ycomb or ybar **in y-direction** without stacking in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185273/how-to-do-a-shift-offset-of-ycomb-or-ybar-in-y-direction-without-stacking-in) , but it has problem as **it also shifts the point in the legend!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can offset the plot using `\addplot [yshift=1cm, legend image post style={yshift=-1cm}]`.

Comment: So, it looks like internally the mark in the legend is part of the plot, not part of the legend or the `legendentry`.

Comment: Is there a variable that I can access that tells me the current size of the plot so I can shift in something approximately proportional to the plot size? `\addplot [yshift=0.5\currentyaxislength, ...`

Comment: @alfC: No, but you could define a macro `\def\myheight{5cm}` and use that to set the `height` of the axis and to shift your plot.

Comment: Also, I was wondering that maybe there is a "substyle" that controls only the curve and not the lengend, for example `\addplot[curve draw style={yshift=1cm}]` so the shift doesn't have to be repeated. no?

Comment: @alfC: I don't think that exists, but you can define your own: `\pgfplotsset{shift plot/.style={yshift=#1, legend image post style={yshift=-#1}}}`. Then you can shift the plot by setting `shift plot=1cm`.